# Feebase Search Service jQuery call breaks when filter is added

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter, freebase

I am calling the freebase Search Service with jQuery in my code like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search",
    data: {filter: afilter,
        query: aquery, 
        limit:1},
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: callback
});
```

but I get service unavailable 503 every time I set aFilter to something. For example when I set aFilter = "(any type:/film/film/ )" it will never return and then for a short time even other queries where I omit the filter will not work either. For example, one of the URL's it made is : [https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?callback=jQuery15208622465366047221_1323023627389&filter=%28any+type%3A%2Ffilm%2Ffilm%2F++%29&query=something&limit=1&_=1323024223282](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?callback=jQuery15208622465366047221_1323023627389&filter=%28any%20type:/film/film/%20%20%29&query=something&limit=1&_=1323024223282)

That URL does not work but if you manually change what jQuery put for filter to what I have above it works : https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?callback=jQuery15208622465366047221_1323023627389&query=something&limit=1&_=1323024223282&filter=%28any%20type:/film/film%29

So basically how do I call the Freebase Search Service using jQuery and with a filter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra "/  " (slash and two spaces) in the filter of the first url.

This is not a valid filter:
(any type:/film/film/  )

this is:
(any type:/film/film)

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to fix it, I no longer get the 503 error!